# Email attachement in Laravel

Tags: php, email, export-to-csv, email-attachments, laravel-mail

I am working on Laravel file attachment. I have to send CSV file as attachment in mail without downloading the file to my server. When I click the submit button it didnot send email with file attachment.

**My Controller:**

```
$data["email"] = $request->recipient_email;
$data["subject"] = 'Cashup Report for '. $venue->name;
$data["bodyMessage"] = $venue->name.' from '.$start.' to '.$end ;

 $excel_file = Excel::create(uniqid().'Cashups', function($excel) use($transactions,$start,$end,$venue) {
      $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) use($transactions,$start,$end,$venue) {
      $sheet->loadView('excel.cashups', array('transactions' => $transactions, 'start'=> $start, 'end' => $end, 'venue' => $venue));
      });
 });

     //Feedback mail to client
 Mail::send('emails.cashups_report', $data, function($message) use ($data,$excel_file){
    $message->from(config('mail.from.address'));
    $message->to($data["email"]);
    $message->subject($data["subject"]);
    //Attach PDF doc
    $message->attachData($excel_file,'cashups-report.xlsx');
});
```

I dont know where i am going wrong. I have already put much time over this but didn't find any solution.
Any guidence in this regards will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using the code below. I tried my level best to explain everything in the comments of the code.

```
//function to generate the csv to be attached in your email
public function createCSV()
{
    
    $myData = MyModel::where(myConditions)->get(['col1','col2','col3']);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    //header without attachment; this instructs the function not to download the csv
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=myCsvFile.csv");

    //Temporarily open a file and store it in a temp file using php's wrapper function php://temp. You can also use php://memory but I prefered temp.

    $Myfile = fopen('php://temp', 'w');

    //state headers / column names for the csv
    $headers = array('col_name1','col_name2','col_name3');

    //write the headers to the opened file
    fputcsv($Myfile, $headers);

    //parse data to get rows
    foreach ($myData as $data) {
        $row=array(
            $data->col1,
            $data->col2,
            $data->col3,
        );

        //write the data to the opened file;
        fputcsv($Myfile, $row);
    }
    //rewind is a php function that sets the pointer at begining of the file to handle the streams of data
    rewind($Myfile);

    //stream the data to Myfile
    return stream_get_contents($Myfile);
}
```

second function: this sends the email to receipients with the csv attached

```
            public function sendEmail()
        {
                Mail::send('path_to_your_view.My_view', array(''),
                function($message){
                    $message->to(explode(',', env('EMAILS')))
                    ->subject('Email Subject')
                    ->attachData($this->createCSV(), "MyfileName.csv");
                });
}
    /*......¯\_(ツ)_/¯......
       It works on my computer*/
```

Best of luck! :)